# change the word order in "confer a degree on him"

Tags: word-order, alternatives

When I looked up the word "confer" I found these example sentences:

> "The university conferred a degree on him"
>
> "A degree was conferred on him by the University"

What if I need to say about "him" first? I couldn't find if the following is correct:

> "He was conferred with a degree by the university"

Is it correct? If not, what verb should I use to keep the sense and the order of the words in the sentence above?

Comment: Probably "he earned his degree" or "he received his degree"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Confer* is monotransitive: it takes only a direct object, not an indirect object, and the recipient of what is conferred must be expressed with a preposition phrase, usually headed by *on* or *upon*, although *to* and *with* are found in very old writings.

> <sup>ok</sup>The university conferred a degree on him. *BUT NOT*
>   <sup>∗</sup> The university conferred him a degree.

Consequently only the direct object, the degree, may stand as the subject of a passive construction.

> <sup>ok</sup>A degree was conferred on him by the univesity. *BUT NOT*
>   <sup>∗</sup> He was conferred a degree by the university.

If you need to make *he* the subject of a passive construction, you must use another verb such as *grant* or *award*:

> <sup>ok</sup>He was granted a degree by the university.
>   <sup>ok</sup>He was awarded a degree by the university.

Of course you may make *he* the subject of an active verb such as *earn*

> <sup>ok</sup>He earned a degree from the university.

ADDED:
Arrowfar points out that your variant *be conferred with* has appeared in a number of Irish, Australian and South Asian sources: *He was conferred with a degree*. The active version is much rarer however; I take this to be an error derived from confusion with the use of *confer with* in the sense have a discussion with.

Answer (score 0):

One options that is not too common, but definitely still in use, is:

> He was admitted to the degree by the university.

With this form, it would be common to name the degree in question. Also, depending on the context, it could be a bit redundant to say "the university" without naming it too. So you might have:

> He was admitted to the degree of Doctor of Philosophy by the University of Edinburgh